# How do I hande users when running Google AppEngine on localhost?

Tags: google-app-engine, python-2.7

In the following code, user is alway None when running on localhost. I assume that there's a way to preload with data, but I can't figure out how.

```
from google.appengine.api import users
user = users.get_current_user()
```

What's the "correct" way to handle users when running on localhost?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always login with the *virtual* user on localhost through this address `http://localhost:8080/_ah/login` (if you are running on default 8080 port).

But usually you would redirect your users to a login page using the [`users.create_login_url()`](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/users/loginurls) and it will handle it correctly on localhost and on production.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't need to do anything special, and `get_current_user` should not always be None.

Are you sure you're actually logging in a user? You may need to set your handler in app.yaml to `login: required` to redirect the user to a login form.